# Timeout Error - how to fix Google drive api for Google Spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, timeout, macos-mojave

I met a TimeoutError in running Python code

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-06414818a9b8> in <module>
      6 credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('test.json', scope)
      7 
----> 8 gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
      9 
     10 wks = gc.open("reivewapi").sheet1

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/__init__.py in authorize(credentials, client_class)
     36     """
     37     client = client_class(auth=credentials)
---> 38     client.login()
     39     return client

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py in login(self)
     49 
     50             http = httplib2.Http()
---> 51             self.auth.refresh(http)
     52 
     53         self.session.headers.update({

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py in refresh(self, http)
    543                   request.
    544         """
--> 545         self._refresh(http)
    546 
    547     def revoke(self, http):

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _refresh(self, http)
    747         """
    748         if not self.store:
--> 749             self._do_refresh_request(http)
    750         else:
    751             self.store.acquire_lock()

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _do_refresh_request(self, http)
    778         resp, content = transport.request(
    779             http, self.token_uri, method='POST',
--> 780             body=body, headers=headers)
    781         content = _helpers._from_bytes(content)
    782         if resp.status == http_client.OK:

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py in request(http, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
    280     return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
    281                          redirections=redirections,
--> 282                          connection_type=connection_type)
    283 
    284 

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1924                         headers,
   1925                         redirections,
-> 1926                         cachekey,
   1927                     )
   1928         except Exception as e:

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1593 
   1594         (response, content) = self._conn_request(
-> 1595             conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
   1596         )
   1597 

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1499             try:
   1500                 if conn.sock is None:
-> 1501                     conn.connect()
   1502                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
   1503             except socket.timeout:

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in connect(self)
   1354             break
   1355         if not self.sock:
-> 1356             raise socket_err
   1357 
   1358 

~/miniconda3/envs/udacity/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in connect(self)
   1287                 if has_timeout(self.timeout):
   1288                     sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
-> 1289                 sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
   1290 
   1291                 self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)

TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

**I've created credentials, downloaded it and shared it with my Spreadsheet. I also enable the google drive api and google spreadsheet api. I really want to know what can i do now.**

Here is my code,

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('test.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("reivewapi").sheet1
reviews = sheet.get_all_records()
```

I really want to connect to the google spreadsheet. 
My system is Mojave, don't know if it affects. THANKS for help.

Comment: I am coming across exactly the same problem as you. I guess the problem is with the network proxy. I have tried to migrate to the v4 api and switch to pygsheet. The problem remains. Are you located in China too? The problem may come from VPN connection to google server. Hope someone could confirm the problem.